# Question the Logarithmic Integral

Tags: calculus, functions

Background: I'm working on some different kind of functions. I've composed a sum of x's Base 2, Base 3, .. , Base n concept.

$f(x,n) = L{g_2}(x) + L{g_3}(x) + L{g_ \cdots } + L{g_n}(x)$

Question: *Is that the logarithmic integral? i.e. `Li()` concept.*

I'm researching series, sequences, and had a year of Calculus at one time. Or why is the Logarithmic Integral abstracted?

Research: Yes $f(x,n)$ is divergent, also? Next, $Li(x)$ cannot be solved directly?, is what I always thought. Though, I have no mathematicians to ask, such questions.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. The logarithmic integral is $\text{li}(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t}{\ln t}$, which doesn't really have anything to do with your $f(x,n)$.

Comment: OK, you're right then, it doesn't have anything to do with what I am asking. The only "connection" is if summing consecutive bases of Log(x), could have had a connection to li(x)? ** So, why is li(x) not solvable? Only numerically approachable?

Comment: Well, it simply turns out that the set of functions that mathematicians had defined by the eighteenth century ($\sin$, $\cos$, $\exp$, $\log$, and so on), known as 'elementary functions', are not sufficient to express an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{\ln x}$. Think of it like this: if you had never heard of the function $\ln x$, then you would say that $\int\frac{1}{x}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$ was not analytically solvable. We therefore have to **define** the function $\ln x$ as the unique antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ that takes the value $0$ at $x=1$, and then can prove its properties.

Comment: @Prasiortle Thank you very much.